# java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\USER\.AndroidStudio2.1\system\port.lock (Access is denied)

Tags: java, android, java-8, javac

I've already installed the JDK and put it in the right path, now I'm trying to install Android Studio. When it finishes installing, I try to start it, but it returns this message:

[image: screenshot of error]

I've already done the tick hidden icon and apply and tick again, like the question before, but I still get this error.

Comment: Did you try running as an Administrator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio can't open (port.lock access denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40521069/android-studio-cant-open-port-lock-access-denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

though if you are using it as an administrator account it should not have problem,if you using from another account in windows try running as administrator should fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I've hidden the particular user folder by mistake. Unhiding that folder made my Android Studio work normal