# How to Resolve 'port.lock' error on opening Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I open the android studio, it gives me the following error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\radiology.AndroidStudio3.1\config\port.lock (Access is
>   denied) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method) at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)

Comment: There seem to be duplicate questions on SO. What have you tried and why do previous answers not work for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio can't open (port.lock access denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40521069/android-studio-cant-open-port-lock-access-denied)